# さっきは随分と楽しそうだったな

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

I am reading through my first book in Japanese, Murakami, and came across a sentence and I can't decide if it's a statement or question:

> さっきは随分と楽しそうだったな

I believe this can mean:

> "Looked like you were having a lot of fun!" *or* "What happened to all that fun you were having?"

Comment: Where in the sentence you think it makes a question statement?

Answer (score 3):

It means "You seemed to be having a lot of fun!" or "You seemed to be having a lot of fun, huh?". As sentence-end particles, な and ね mildly seek agreement like "huh?" in English, but that does not mean it's a true question that expects an answer.

Depending on the context, this statement may be a sarcastic remark, in which case your second translation may work, too. But it's an "implication" at most rather than a literal translation.